# Hook function in single process

Tags: windows, process, kernel, hook

Can anybody tell me how can i hook from kernel driver function only for single process. For example ZwQueryInformationProcess.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in windows kernel. ZwXXX functions of ntoskrnl are native APIs. They are global common functions. All processes in user mode are using one copy of the function. There is no copy-on-write or something else in kernel.
You can implement this by using this way:

1. hook ZwQueryInformationProcess of ntdll.dll of special process in
   user mode.
2. Add a filter in your hook function in kernel mode. If
   current process context is not what you wanted. Pass through it.

That's all.

Thanks.